# Azure Data Factory Pipeline : Scheduling to run on Every Saturday @ 1:00 AM

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

**Environments**

- Azure data factory
- SQL Server on Azure IaaS

**Problem**

- I want to create a azure data factory pipeline (*with copy activity*) which can run on **Every Saturday @ 1:00 AM.**
- Is it possible to create the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that, just edit pipeline config or create one manually as stated in this answer.

Your output dataset availability should look like this:

```
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 7,
            "offset": "01:00:00",
            "style": "StartOfInterval"
        }
```

And your activity schedule should look like this:

```
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 7,
                "offset": "01:00:00",
                "style": "StartOfInterval"
            }
```

This is UTC time scheduling. The only thing is that this should be provisioned on that same day before execution, so you do it on Saturday and from then on this activity will be executed every Saturday.

Hope this helped, this is how I did it!

Kind greetings!